# How to show a value from array that relates to the value of another array, javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have the name show up with the score that relates to that name. So if the highest score is 98 I want Joels name to show up in the display where is says name here.

```
var names = ["Ben", "Joel", "Judy", "Anne"];
var scores = [88, 98, 77, 88];
var average;
var total = 0;
var highestScore = 0;

var $ = function (id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

var displayResults = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        total = total + scores[i];       //both are numbers so adds
        if (scores[i] > highestScore) {
            highestScore = scores[i];
        }          
    }

    //then calculate the average and display
    average = parseInt(total/scores.length);
    document.getElementById("results_header").innerHTML = ("Results");
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = ("\nAverage score is " + average + "\nHigh score = Name here with a score of " + highestScore); 
};

window.onload = function () {
    //$("add").onclick = addScore;
    $("display_results").onclick = displayResults;
    //$("display_scores").onclick = displayScores;
};
```

Comment: If you're interested in writing better code, I've added detailed explanations to my answer for solving each step of your problem. If this is a homework assignment and you submitted code like ehsan gave you,  I'd give you a very low mark.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try it :

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="results"></p>
        <button id="display_results">Show</button>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
               var names = ["Ben", "Joel", "Judy", "Anne"];
                var scores = [88, 98, 77, 88];
                var average;
                var total = 0;
                var highestScore = 0;
                var hightName = "";
                function displayResults () {
                    for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
                            total = total + scores[i];       //both are numbers so adds
                                if (scores[i] > highestScore) {
                                    highestScore = scores[i];
                                    hightName = names[i];
                                }
                    }

                //then calculate the average and display
                        average = parseInt(total/scores.length);
                        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = ("\nAverage score is " + average + "\n High score = " + hightName + " with a score of " +  highestScore);

                };
            
                    //$("add").onclick = addScore;
                   $(document).ready(function(){
                       $("#display_results").click(function(){
                           displayResults();
                       })
                       
                   })

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is this Answer different from http://stackoverflow.com/a/38415234/ ?

Comment: "try it" is about the laziest explanation i've ever seen

Answer (score 1):

These are all pretty basic operations to perform in JavScript. I hope you find this information helpful.

I've provided detailed explanations for the techniques used in this answer below. All snippets can be run in your browser. Click <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> below to see the results.

```js
// input data
var names = ["Ben", "Joel", "Judy", "Anne"]
var scores = [88, 98, 77, 88]

// this is a common way to sum the numbers in an array
var total = scores.reduce(function(x,y) { return x + y }, 0)

// average = sum of scores / number of scores
var average = total / scores.length

// use Math.max to find the highest score
var highScore = Math.max.apply(null, scores)

// get the name matching the highest score
var highScoreName = names[scores.indexOf(highScore)]

// output the information to the console
// alternative: use innerHTML or something else to print to the DOM
console.log("total: %d", total)
console.log("average: %d", average)
console.log("highest score: %s had %d", highScoreName, highScore)
```

---

**Summing an array of numbers:**

You could use a `for` loop or a `forEach` but that is for cavemen.

```js
var scores = [88, 98, 77, 88]
var total = 0

for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
  total = total + scores[i]
}

console.log("total scores: %d", total)
// 351
```

Once you learn about higher order functions like [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) you will never go back to the imperative nightmares of your past

```js
var scores = [88, 98, 77, 88]
var total = scores.reduce(function(sum, score) { return sum + score }, 0)

console.log("total scores: %d", total)
// 351
```

Without smothering you with too many details, the reducing function `function(sum, score) { sum + score }` will be called once for each element in our `scores` array. The return value of the function will be used as the `sum` the next time it is called

```
iteration     sum       score      return
-----------------------------------------------------------------
#1            0         88         0 + 88 (88)
#2            88        98         88 + 98 (186)
#3            186       77         186 + 77 (263)
#4            263       88         263 + 88 (351) <-- final value

var total = scores.reduce(function(sum, score) { return sum + score }, 0)
// 351
```

---

**Finding the max number of an array:**

Again, we could use neanderthal techniques like this

```js
var max
var scores = [88, 98, 77, 88]
for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
  if (max === undefined)
    max = scores[i]
  else if (max < scores[i])
    max = scores[i]
}

console.log("max score: %d", max)
// 98
```

But we're much smarter than that, right? We *could* reach for `Array.prototype.reduce` again but there's an even better way this time.

[Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) will tell us the maximum of the inputs provided

```js
var max = Math.max(1, 5, 9, 3, 10, 6)
console.log('max: %d', max)
// 10
```

It'd be nice if we could just write `Math.max(scores)` to get the value for our `highScore` variable, but Math.max only works on numbers, not arrays. To get around this, we can use [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) which applies a function to an array of arguments. This is perfect for our needs

```js
var scores = [88, 98, 77, 88]

// this is the same as writing Math.max(88, 98, 77, 88)
// but .apply allows us to keep the score values in an array
var max = Math.max.apply(null, scores)

console.log("max score: %d", max)
// 98
```

---

**Linking the high score to the corresponding name:**

Once we have the `highScore` value, we have to find the name of the person that matches that score. All we have to do is fine the *index* of the `highScore` value in the `scores` array, then look-up the value from the `names` array with that same index.

Because the `highScore` value is a known value from the `scores` array, we can use [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) with the guarantee that a valid index will be returned.

```js
var scores = [88, 98, 77, 88]
var highScore = Math.max.apply(null, scores)
var highScoreIndex = scores.indexOf(highScore)

console.log("highScore: %d, highScoreIndex: %d", highScore, highScoreIndex)
// highScore: 98, highScoreIndex: 1
```

We see `highScoreIndex: 1` because **array indexes start with 0** and count up. An array index of `1` actually refers to the *second* element in the array.

So now all we have to do is look up the name using index `1` to get the corresponding name value

```js
var names = ["Ben", "Joel", "Judy", "Anne"]
var scores = [88, 98, 77, 88]
var highScore = Math.max.apply(null, scores)
var highScoreIndex = scores.indexOf(highScore)
var highScoreName = names[highScoreIndex]

console.log("high score of %d by %s", highScore, highScoreName)
// high score of 98 by Joel
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the i value (the positioning of the score in scores array). This **i value corresponds with the person in the persons array**. Use this i value to select the person.

To make stuff easier you could use an object to associate name (string) with score (int) like:

```
 var test = {"Ben": 88, "Joel": 98, "Judy": 77, "Anne": 88}
```

Then you would need to modify the for loop.

Comment: What? Is that like a compliment or... :D?

Answer (score 0):

As `names` and `scores` arrays have same `.length`, you can use same `i` variable to select item within `names` array as is used to select item in `scores`.

Declare `name` variable

```
var name = "";
```

set `name` variable

```
if (scores[i] > highestScore) {
  highestScore = scores[i];
  name = names[i];
}
```

display `name` variable

```
document.getElementById("results")
.innerHTML = "\nAverage score  is " 
          + average 
          + "\nHigh score = " 
          + name 
          + " here with a score of " 
          + highestScore;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the index instead of the highest score and use it to get the name. I have changed your code to support it and added comment 'Changes' to wherever the changes are,

```
 var names = ["Ben", "Joel", "Judy", "Anne"];
    var scores = [88, 98, 77, 88];
    var average;
    var total = 0;
    var highScoreIndex = 0;// Changes

    var $ = function (id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

    var displayResults = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
                total = total + scores[i];       //both are numbers so adds
                    if (scores[i] > highestScore) {
                highestScoreIndex = i; // Changes
            }

           }

    //then calculate the average and display
            average = parseInt(total/scores.length);
            document.getElementById("results_header").innerHTML =   
     ("Results");
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = ("\nAverage score  
          is " + average + "\nHigh score = " + names[highestScoreIndex] + " with a score of " +    
        scores[highestScoreIndex]); //Changes


    };

    window.onload = function () {
        //$("add").onclick = addScore;
        $("display_results").onclick = displayResults;
        //$("display_scores").onclick = displayScores;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else {
names[names.length] = nameInput;
```

convert to numbers

> scoreInput = Number(scoreInput);

```
scores[scores.length] = scoreInput;
```

and

> //then calculate the average and highest score

```
var displayResults = function () {
```

Reset total

> total = 0;

```
    for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
            total = total + scores[i];      
                if (scores[i] > highestScore) {
            highestScore = scores[i];
            name = names[i];
```